# How can I clear routes on google.map?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

When I load more than one route, the previous route is not removed.
Many people said to set `directionsDisplay.setMap` to `null`, but that doesn't work.
It looks like the route is on the map and not on `directionsDisplay`.
This is my code that doesn't work:

```
NgMap.getMap('mapShop').then(function(map) {
    $scope.googleMaps = map;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(null);
                    directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.googleMaps);

    // get geolocation for center map and marker
    NavigatorGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function(position) {
        $scope.latitude = $routeParams.latitude;
        $scope.longitude = $routeParams.longitude;
        $scope.urlLocalCard = "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=" + $routeParams.latitude + "," + $routeParams.longitude + "&saddr=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&ll=" + $routeParams.latitude + "," + $routeParams.longitude + "&z=10&t=s";
        var request = {
            origin: position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude,
            destination: $routeParams.latitude + ',' + $routeParams.longitude,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                alert('Google route unsuccesfull!');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the JS console?

Comment: In console show any errors.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you lose reference to the old `directionsDisplay` by assigning the latter variable to the new instance of `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer`. Move the `directionsDisplay` and `directionsService` to global scope.

```
var directionsDisplay,
    directionsService;

// Update global reference upon Google map loads
function initMap(){

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

}

NgMap.getMap('mapShop').then(function(map) {

       $scope.googleMaps = map;

       directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(null);

       // rest of code       

});
```

Comment: in this case show this error: "google is not defined"

Comment: That's a common mistake, update the global reference after the library loads using `iniMap` callback

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @HugoLeite, see updated answer. I am not AngularJS guy, but the same principle applies here in pure JavaScript.